# How do I prevent users from entering HTML tags in a safecracker form?

Tags: safecracker, php, forms, validation

I'm working on an EE powered website which also serves data to a mobile app. I'm trying to make a safecracker form, but one of the fields cannot have HTML code in it or the app breaks. How do I stop people from entering HTML? Here's the field's line in the safecracker form:

```
<input type="text" name="snippet" id="snippet" value="{snippet}">
```

At the moment I think I need to use htmlspecialchars, but I have no idea how to implement it into safecracker. I'm also assuming that it might be easier to apply htmlspecialchars to the output, but unfortunately I do not have access to the apps source code.

Comment: Have you looked at removing html tags with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need to look into that channel preferences under "Channel Posting Preferences". You can see "Default HTML formatting in channel entries" and set it to "Convert HTML into character entities".

I hope, it would work for you.